# 'Do not dispose objects multiple times' warning from csv import method

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable, csvhelper

I read through quite a few posts on SO regarding this and still need some help understanding this please.

CodeAnalysis is saying this method is disposing objects twice. Actually, it is warning me about this for two objects in the method; once for the `file.InputStream` and once for the `reader` object

Here is my code:

```
public void SaveCsvData(HttpPostedFileBase file, int vendorId)
        {
            var listCsvImport = new List<CsvImport>();

            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
                using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader))
                {

                    int count = 0;
                    while (csvReader.Read())
                    {
                        ...<snip>...

                        listCsvImport.Add(record);
                    }
                    _db.CsvImports.AddRange(listCsvImport);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
...<snip>...

            }
            catch (CsvBadDataException ex)
            {
                log.Error("Invalid data in the CSV file, terminating process...");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Csv import failed, no data was saved.", ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

thanks

Comment: Are you missing `{...}` for `using (var reader...`?

Comment: This is probably caused by the fact that CsvReader, disposes of reader, so you don't need 2 using statements. This assumes that your actual code compile unlike the code you have posted.

Comment: @DavidG no sir, it is ok to stack using statements like that if you want to nest them.  Nice thing is if something goes wrong they'll all dispose in the order they were instanted

Comment: @JBenjamin Yes, you CAN do it, but it's generally recommended to NOT do it.

Answer (score 2):

`using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader))` already disposes reader object, so you don't need to use `using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))`.

Comment: What makes you think that the first line disposes `reader`?

Comment: @DavidG 'Do not dispose objects multiple times' warning, maybe?

Comment: Old question/answer, I know. But the following GitHub issue confirms the behaviour where CsvReader disposes the passed in StreamReader https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/396 (Personally I would dispose the StreamReader rather than the CsvReader, unless instantiating both at the same time.)